# Quantity Box with +/- button having a limit

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        // This button will increment the value
        $('.qtyplus').click(function (e) {
            // Stop acting like a button
            e.preventDefault();
            // Get the field name
            fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
            // Get its current value
            var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());
            // If is not undefined
            if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
                // Increment
                $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal + 1);

            }
            else  {
                // Otherwise put a 0 there
                $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
            }
        });
        // This button will decrement the value till 0
        $(".qtyminus").click(function (e) {
            // Stop acting like a button
            e.preventDefault();
            // Get the field name
            fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
            // Get its current value
            var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());
            // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal >= 0) {
                // Decrement one
                $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal - 1);
            } else {
                // Otherwise put a 0 there
                $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
            }
        });
    });
```

How do I set a limit on this box? I don't want to have over 100 quantity, so if the user keep hitting the +  button, the quantity when it gets to 100 should stop increasing.

```
if(currentVal == 100)
{
  $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal);
}
```

I don't think that is correct, I need some help

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/laelitenetwork/puJ6G/
The Jsfiddle is here

Comment: can you post HTML as well? or just jsfiddle?

Comment: you're using the same `$(blah)` in so many code branches you can tidy up your code if you keep a copy of it.

Comment: also, `/* get int */ var i = val | 0; /* increment it */ i = i + foo; /* check against your limit */ if (i > 100) /* and set to limit if outside range */ i = 100; /* set it back */ val = i;`

Comment: `field` is not a valid HTML5 attribute. You should use `data-field` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a simple logic that will probably help you. Since you have not provided any HTML, I have crafted a simple structure (which might differ from yours):

```
<input type="text" name="field1" value="0" />
<button class="qty" type="button" data-func="plus" data-field="field1">+1</button>
<button class="qty" type="button" data-func="minus" data-field="field1">-1</button>
```

Note that:

1. Custom HTML attributes are using the `data-` prefix, such as `data-field` and `data-func`.
2. I have given both buttons a common class of `qty` — we can discern which button is clicked on later. This simplifies the selector, and also prevents redundant code blocks (one for each button, which can be bloated easily).

Now here is the jQuery logic:

```
$('.qty').click(function() {
    var $t = $(this),
        $in = $('input[name="'+$t.data('field')+'"]'),
        val = parseInt($in.val()),
        valMax = 100,
        valMin = 0;

    // Check if a number is in the field first
    if(isNaN(val) || val < valMin) {
        // If field value is NOT a number, or
        // if field value is less than minimum,
        // ...set value to 0 and exit function
        $in.val(valMin);
        return false;
    } else if (val > valMax) {
        // If field value exceeds maximum,
        // ...set value to max
        $in.val(valMax);
        return false;
    }

    // Perform increment or decrement logic
    if($t.data('func') == 'plus') {
        if(val < valMax) $in.val(val + 1);
    } else {
        if(val > valMin) $in.val(val - 1);
    }
});
```

Pretty straightforward, eh? You can even enhance my example by disabling the `<button>` elements when the threshold is reached, but since you didn't mention it I guess it's more of a gimmick than a necessity.

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/2aC5C/3/

Comment: Yea, that works pretty well, I should have had a max and min value in there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your increment logic do:

```
if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal <= 100) {
```

I think that should work.